# Unable to find the suitable masks to calculate bad pixel percentage for disparity map

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, stereo-3d

I am working on the stereo vision problem and I need to calculate the bad pixel percentage. I have the depth map ground truth of the cones image, I need to calculate the bad pixel percentage for 3 categories. As given in the middlebury site :

[image: bad pixel categories].

As seen in the screen-shot, here are three masks: non-occ, all and disc. How do I generate the images for each of them. I tried with threshold function as well as edge detection function. The results were far from the desired. I know the formula for bad pixel percentage. But first I have to generate the non occlude image, discontinuity image,etc. But I am not able to figure out which image processing will generate any of the images...

The input image(ground truth) is :

[image: groundtruth].

These are the results I want to achieve...

The desired results are:

For non-occluded :

[image: non-occ]

and for discontinuity image :

[image: disc]

and finally for including all occluded, non-occluded regions in an image :

[image: all]

Looking at the images, intuitively I used thresholding and edge detection methods to generate the non occluded region images and my results were far from the ideal.

I think this is not the right way.

Which are masks that one one must apply obtain those results?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what are your results and what do you desire? Apart from the links there is very little information given

Comment: The desired results are on the site.  My results are not valid as they are far from ideal. Moreover the question is about the right approach to get the images shown in the site.

Comment: the question should be selfcontained in the sense that it is not necessary to follow links that contain essential information

Comment: As I understand, the various images(non-occ,all,disc) are got by applying a suitable mask to the disparity image obtained. However I am uncertain of the mask that's applied. I also tried the Laplacian mask but it did not work... I am looking for a clue or solution to this problem..

Comment: Thank you @tobi303 for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you @Eswar for the edits. Looking forward for the answer..